# What does it mean to have a "masked" clickhouse-server?

Tags: service, clickhouse

I am new to clickhouse.
After several unfruitful attempts to install version 18.16.1, I purged both clickhouse-server and clickhouse-client (`sudo dpkg --purge clickhouse-server` and `sudo dpkg --purge clickhouse-common`).

After I made sure that `sudo apt --fix-broken install` did not return any error message, I went over and installed both the client and server using apt: `sudo apt install clickhouse-server clickhouse-client`.

Upon installation I received the following warning:

> dpkg: warning: clickhouse-server: conffile
> '/etc/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service' is not a plain file or
> symlink (= '/dev/null')

Trying `service clickhouse-server status` returned:

> ● clickhouse-server.service
> Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit clickhouse-server.service is masked.)
> Active: inactive (dead)

**What does it mean to have a masked service?** I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017311/what-is-a-masked-service) on AskUbuntu, but it seems specific to PostgreSQL. Am I OK to implement the solution provided in there to "unmask" the clickhouse service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not related to CH. Related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd.

https://medium.com/@codingmaths/service-masking-in-linux-f7265d9b2181

mask is a stronger version of disable. Using disable all symlinks of the specified unit file are removed....

Answer (score 0):

Denny Crane was right.

You need to run the following commands

```
systemctl unmask clickhouse-server
systemctl start clickhouse-server
```